# regex capture group which might not be present

Tags: regex, logfile, capturing-group

I'm running a regex through some log files.
The capture groups should capture some relevant fields.
I'd like to know if the logfile mentions a successful ending of the job or not. This can be concluded by the presence or absence of the string "Job executed successfully"

My regex so far:
`^Job started at\s'(\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)'\s+orderno\s+-\s+'(\w+)'\s+runno\s+-\s+'(\d+)'[\s\S]+Host1\s'([\w.]+)'\[([\w-]+)\] username '([\w\\]+)' - Host2\s'([\w.]+)'\[([\w-]+)\] username '([\w\\]+)'[\s\S]+(Job executed successfully)?[\s\S]+Job ended at\s'(\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)'\s+Elapsed time\s\[([\d.]+)sec\]\sCPU usage\s\[([\d.]+)sec]`

(I'm kind of new to regex, so it will not be perfect at all and needs some hardening)

A sample log with successful ending:
The regex above will only work when the question mark behind "(Job executed successfully)?" is removed which should not be necessary in my opinion.

> Job started at '0902 23:56:00:367' orderno - '0tzh0'  runno - '00064'
>     Number of transfers - 1
>
> Host1 'Local'[Windows-LOCAL] username 'xxx\xxx' -  Host2 'xxx.xxx.xx'[Unix-SFTP] username 'xxx'
>
> Local host is: xxx - Windows 200x [601] Service Pack 1 build 7601 - Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
>
> ********** Starting transfer #1 out of 1 ***************
>     Transfer #1 completed successfully
>
> Job executed successfully. exiting.
>
> Job ended at '0902 23:56:07:138'
>     Elapsed time [7sec] CPU usage [0.15sec]

A sample log with unsuccessful ending:
The regex above works like it should.

> Job started at '0831 15:26:00:365' orderno - '0tuq5'  runno - '00030'
>     Number of transfers - 4
>
> Host1 'Local'[Windows-LOCAL] username 'xxx\xxx' -  Host2 'xxx.xxx.xx'[Unix-SFTP] username 'xxx'
>
> Local host is: xxx - Windows 200x [601] Service Pack 1 build 7601 - Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
>
> ********** Starting transfer #1 out of 4 ***************
>     Unable to connect to SSH server on 'xxx.xxx.xx': SFTP_Connect : psftp_connect failed : ssh_init: Network error: Connection timed out
>   .
>
> Connection to host sftp.onenet.be could not be established
>
> Job ended at '0831 15:26:21:426'
>
> Elapsed time [21sec] CPU usage [0.0sec]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minimal change to your regex, you could use this one:

```
^Job started at\s'(\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)'\s+orderno\s+-\s+'(\w+)'\s+runno\s+-\s+'(\d+)'[\s\S]+?Host1\s'([\w.]+)'\[([\w-]+)\] username '([\w\\]+)' - Host2\s'([\w.]+)'\[([\w-]+?)\] username '([\w\\]+)'[\s\S]+?(?:(Job executed successfully)[\s\S]+?)?Job ended at\s'(\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)'\s+Elapsed time\s\[([\d.]+)sec\]\sCPU usage\s\[([\d.]+)sec]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^-----------------------------------^^
```

(Main changes indicated by `^` above)

I also converted some quantifiers to lazy which should make things a little faster.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2brWKb/1)

Your current regex would match everything till the end due to greedy matching of `[\s\S]+` and backtrack (from right to left) and test for `(Job executed successfully)?[\s\S]+`, and there, `[\s\S]+` will match as soon as `Job ended` gets found.

In the above way, we check from left to right each character until we get to the part we need, i.e. `Job executed successfully` if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `PCRE`, you could use the fabulous `\Q...\E` sequence along with a neg. lookahead:

```
^\QJob started\E
(?:(?!\QJob ended\E).)+?
^\QJob executed successfully\E
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qoqXh4/1/) (and mind the `multiline`, `verbose` and `singleline` modifiers!).

If not, the whole expression gets somewhat unreadable:

```
^Job started(?:(?!Job ended).)+?^Job executed successfully
```